# Struggling with Unexpected Cross-Thread and Halt

Tags: c#, multithreading, audio, naudio

I was creating playlist function for my own audio player application with NAudio Library, and completed source code. However, at Debugging, **InvalidOperationException** occured, and It says cross-thread occured exception.

So, I declared **CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false** on constructor of form. The exception doesn't occured, but program halts at specific line.

I didn't plan my application as multithreading application so any multithreading components are not used, or declared. but cross-thread exception occured, So I'm very embarrassing now.

This is a declaration and a constructor for frmMain :

```
        AudioFileReader _audioFileReader;
        IWavePlayer _waveOutDevice = new WaveOut();

        static int nowIndex = 0;
        static bool _paused = false;
        static bool _manual_stop = false;

    public frmMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.listMusic.DragOver += new DragEventHandler(this.FileDragOver);
        this.listMusic.DragDrop += new DragEventHandler(this.FileDragDrop);
        this.listMusic.DoubleClick += new EventHandler(this.listDoubleClick);

        _waveOutDevice.PlaybackStopped += new EventHandler<StoppedEventArgs>(this.PlaybackStopped);
    }
```

and Here's the point where cross-thread exception occured.

```
    private void playMusic(int index)
    {
        if(_waveOutDevice.PlaybackState != PlaybackState.Stopped)
            stopMusic();

            _audioFileReader = new AudioFileReader(listMusic.Items[index].SubItems[0].Text); // Exception Occured
            getProperties(listMusic.Items[index].Text);

        _waveOutDevice.Init(_audioFileReader);
        _waveOutDevice.Play();

        btnPlayCtrl.Text = "II";
        nowIndex = index;
        _manual_stop = false;
    }
```

...And, Here's halt point when I declared **CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false**

```
        _waveOutDevice.Init(_audioFileReader); //from foregone source code.
```

It just make application halt, However, It didn't occur any exceptions and pause debugging. when i paused the debugging for analyze it, but debugger pointed here.

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        if (args.Length > 0)
            Application.Run(new frmMain(args[1]));
        else
            Application.Run(new frmMain());
    } // Debugger Points Here
```

Comment: Setting `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false` will stop it from detecting the error, but it won't stop the error from causing problems that result in your program halting.  You probably want to take that out so that you can see what is actually happening.

Answer (score 1):

**Remove** the `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;` line in your constructor...

Then try moving execution back to the main UI thread like this:

```
    private void playMusic(int index)
    {
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            if (_waveOutDevice.PlaybackState != PlaybackState.Stopped)
                stopMusic();

            _audioFileReader = new AudioFileReader(listMusic.Items[index].SubItems[0].Text); 

            _waveOutDevice.Init(_audioFileReader);
            _waveOutDevice.Play();

            btnPlayCtrl.Text = "II";
            nowIndex = index;
            _manual_stop = false;
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, but  program halts either at `_waveOutDevice.Init(_audioFileReader);`